# Error while running an application (Struts1)

Tags: struts

HTTP Status 404 - /login.do

type Status report

message /login.do

description The requested resource (/login.do) is not available.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.28

What may be the possible cause?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 404 is the generic "file not found" error.
Is this Tomcat 6? Maybe try running your app with higher privileges?
Do you also have log4j? Any tracing in place? Maybe that info could help you find out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues:

1. Have you configured your Struts ActionServlet in `web.xml` correctly?
2. If 1 is yes, have you configured your LoginAction to your `<action>` in `struts-config.xml`?
3. If 2 is yes, what is the error found in Tomcat error log (found in `TOMCAT_HOME/logs`)

Besides that, I can't really help you.